# Как правильно описать создание через интерфейс 2 типов авторов и более?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс, полиморфизм

У меня имеется два типа автора: `ExternalAuthor` и `MainAuthor`.

Я сделал интерфейс `AuthorService` и реализую его двумя классами: `ExternalServiceImpl` и `MainAuthorSericeImpl`. Eсть метод в интерфейсе `addAuthor(Form form)`.

`Form` — это класс для передачи данных. В него я планирую записывать данные из форм. Но проблема в том, что у разных авторов разные поля (есть одинаковы).

Правильно ли будет передавать `Form form` для создания, и дальше в разных реализациях интерфейса использовать только часть данных для создания авторов и записи в БД. Или есть какой-то больше элегантный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте [параметр типа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) в интерфейс `AuthorService`, ограниченный классом `Form`:

```java
public interface AuthorService <T extends Form> {
    void addAuthor(T form);
}
```

Сделайте две реализации форм: `MainForm` и `ExternalForm`. Используйте их в конкретных реализациях `AuthorService`:

```java
public class MainAuthorService implements AuthorService<MainForm> {
    @Override
    public void addAuthor(MainForm form) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```java
public class ExternalAuthorService implements AuthorService<ExternalForm> {
    @Override
    public void addAuthor(ExternalForm form) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Таким образом, в Main-сервис можно будет добавлять только Main-форму, а в External-сервис — только External-форму:

```java
new MainAuthorService().addAuthor(new MainForm());
new ExternalAuthorService().addAuthor(new ExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вполне себе адекватный способ, только и Form тогда тоже надо будет сделать как интерфейс реализуемый для каждого автора по разному.